# How do I use the "Proportional Falloff Tool" to create doughnut frosting as per youtube tutorial?

Tags: modeling

Sorry if I am not posting this properly, its my first time posting and I am not sure the best place to ask questions like this as I seek to learn Blender.

I am following Andrew Price's tutorial here:

https://youtu.be/f5Gb1VK98Wc?list=PLjEaoINr3zgHs8uzT3yqe4iHGfkCmMJ0P&t=2045

And as he talks about at that timestamp, I am trying to make a random edge to the frosting on my doughnut using the proportional falloff tool.  I have turned it on and, like him, selected "random".

My problem comes when I scale my frosting as Andrew does in that Andrew achieves a very nice looking uneven edge to his frosting, however, on mine scaling the frosting object in as he shows, just barely scaled inside the doughnut so that there isnt overlap or globs sticking out of the doughnut, my frosting edge looks too smooth.

I have tried using the tool multiple times, using multiple vertices etc, but I cant achieve a look as wavy as his upon scaling.  What should I be doing?  I feel like this is a complicated question so not sure if there is any appropriate way to ask or any appropriate site since following the simple directions in the tutorial has not provided the desired results.

It does show some wave and so is more realistic than a smooth line, but I can't achieve it to the degree he does and I'd like to be able to properly use this tool.

Thank you!

[image: Mine]

Here you can see it was successful on the inside of the doughnut, but not the outside

Answer (score 2):

Just change the proportional size with the mouse wheel or with <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or set it using the operator result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only select one vertex & make the proportional size big enough to cover the whole donut.